# How to make TabControl.Itemtemplate (TextBlock) occupy full available width

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the `TabControl` (textblock) to occupy the full width available in the window. Equal amount of available space should be get distributed among three tabs (Header, SOP & Variable).

```cs
<TabControl Name="Tabct" Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Header}">
            <local:HeaderUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SOP}">
            <local:SOPUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Variable}">
            <local:VariableUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ITab}">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Run Text="{Binding HeaderName}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar, but instead I used a converter to calculate the `TabControl`'s actual width and distribute them equally among the `TabItems`. Include the Converter below to your View's resources.

**Converter**

```
public class EqualWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var numberOfTabs = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        var actualWidth = (double)value;
        var equalWidth = actualWidth / numberOfTabs;

        // For TabItem's tiny space after the last tab.
        return equalWidth-2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<TabControl Name="Tabct" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <TabItem Header="First Tab" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Tabct, Converter={StaticResource EqualWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Second Tab" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Tabct, Converter={StaticResource EqualWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Third Tab" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Tabct, Converter={StaticResource EqualWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}">
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```